# Restrict User from view based on existing model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-permissions

I have a few really simple views in my `views.py`.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'voting/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """    
        return Poll.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'voting/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'voting/results.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'
```

I also have created a `model` where I store which users are invited to which polls along with some other data.

```
class EligibleVoters(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    encrypted_keypart = models.BinaryField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    decrypted_keypart = models.BinaryField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["user", "poll"]
```

I want to restrict users that aren't invited to a poll from seeing any of these polls.

I think that what I want to do is something like this for each view, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to go.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'voting/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        if EligibleVoters.objects.filter(poll=Poll.objects.id, user=self.request.user.id).exists():
            return Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
        else:
            return render('voting/somethingsomething.html')
            })
```

Should I restrict access to specific polls that way? Also the above code doesn't really work and gives some errors but I'm not sure if I should continue and try to fix it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Filtering the queryset on `eligblevoters`

The `get_queryset` does *not* render the output, it only produces a queryset.

Nevertheless, we can use this to restrict access, by adding extra filtering:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'voting/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DetailView, self).get_queryset().filter
            eligiblevoters__user=self.request.user,
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        )
```

Similar approaches should be used in the other views.

## How does this work

The query works as follows. By defining a `ForeignKey` from `EligibleVoters` to `User` (named `user`), then Django creates an *implicit* relation in reverse: you can for example query with `User.eligblevoters_set` to obtain the related `EligableVoters` queryset. We can also filter on it with `elgiblevoters`.

We thus add two extra filter conditions: `pub_date__lte=timezone.now()` to filter posts that are published before now (now included), and `eligiblevoters__user=self.request.user`. This means that we add a constraint that *at least* one of the related `eligablevoters` should have as `user` the `self.request.user` (the user of this specific session).

So in case there is no such `Post`, then we can not get the `Poll` with the `id` that is requested.

## Render in case the object is not found

We can also render a page in case the object is not found, for example by patching the `.get(..)` function with a `try`-`except` with `Http404`, and then render a specific page, for example:

```
from django.http import Http404

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'voting/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DetailView, self).get_queryset().filter
            eligiblevoters__user=self.request.user,
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        )

    def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(DetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return render(request, 'app/template_not_found.html', {})
```

So here we render a (possibly different template) with here an empty context, although you can of course make this more advanced.

Comment: You are mentioning that `get_queryset` does not render the output. Does that mean that this isn't the right and safe way to do this?

Your solution works but how can I adjust it and give an error message when the user isn't invited, similar to "You are not invited to any polls" or "You aren't allowed to access this poll"?

Comment: Also can you explain a bit more your solution and why it works? Especially this line `eligiblevoters__user=self.request.user`. I'm new to django and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @kstr: give me a few minutes.

Comment: Your answer works for all the views except for the IndexView. I get this error:
`IndexView is missing a QuerySet. Define IndexView.model, IndexView.queryset, or override IndexView.get_queryset().`

Comment: @kstr: did you add a `model=Poll` to your `IndexView`?

Comment: Nevermind I found what was wrong. Your answer was perfect! thank you!

Comment: Oh, just saw your comment. That was exactly what was wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You should add a many-to-many field from Poll to User, using EligibleVoter as a through field:

```
eligible_users = models.ManyToManyField('User', through='EligibleVoter')
```

Now you can do:

```
return Poll.objects.filter(eligible_users=self.request.user, pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```